# PC doing ABSOLUTELY NOTHING when power button is pressed

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

My PC (gtx960, Ryzen7 5800x, 16gb RAM, 700w power supply, and B550m WIFI) is not turning on at all.

I have had the motherboard and CPU tested separately at the store I bought them from (both worked).
I have an old motherboard with an i5 in it, and my PSU (it's quite old), worked with the old m-board.

Furthermore, my PC was working for two months before this happened (one day it just didn't turn on).
Is there anything else that could be the problem? I know for a fact that PC
s can turn on without a GPU, that cannot be the problem, and the fans should at least come on if the RAM that is the problem. I think it must be the power supply, but I don't see how that is possible considering it works with a different motherboard + CPU, and has previously worked with my motherboard.

Anyone got any ideas? (Could it be a bad PSU connection? How is that possible since it worked at the computer store?)

Final piece of information is that I plugged in JUST the PSU leads, RAM, and CPU - nothing happened (after pressing the FLBK BIOS button. I took out the CPU, pressed the BIOS button, and boom, the lights came on on the motherboard.

After doing some more research, I have decided that it could be the 12V ATX 8 PIN power connector (it goes in the top of the motherboard). Mine is a bit too short, and is under a lot of tension. It could possibly have broken (one or more of the wires are no longer connected to their pin in the end of the cable). Anyone know how to test this? I guess I'll have to use a multimeter...

Comment: At a preliminary level try Paperclip test on PSU and check if it powers ON or not in principle. There are plenty of articles on the net explaining how to do a paperclip test on PSU.